# FHIR: Using HEAD for found/not found searches

Tags: hl7-fhir

Is there a way to quickly determine if a search matches anything?  Something like a HEAD request - don't send a body, just send a "total" or the like.  A search with total=0 isn't a 404...or should it be?

Comment: I thought a search with _count=0 would suffice for this, but Grahame's server, Spark, and WildFHIR return results.  `http://spark-dstu2.furore.com/fhir/Patient?_count=0` returns entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an answer to this: _summary=count will return the number of matches without return any actual matches

Answer (score 1):

We probably should make clear whether _count=0 is legal or not.  Can you make a change request?

At the moment, there isn't a way to submit a query and indicate that no rows can come back.  Certainly documenting that as a use of _count=0 would be a possibility, but there was no intention of supporting that when we introduced _count.